# A word to describe that you ate too much so you don't like it anymore now

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, sentence

In our native language we have a word for saying that you can't eat something because you ate too much of it and now you don't like the taste of it (for some time).

When and how we use it:

> No, I don't want to eat waffles, Mom, I ate too much.

Instead of 'I ate too much', we say the word.

Is there a better word/sentence to use there?

Comment: Not a single word, or something you're likely to use with your mum in a casual way, but the phenomenon is known as '[sensory-specific satiety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory-specific_satiety)'. It is "*the declining satisfaction generated by the consumption of a certain type of food*" (and its "*consequent renewal in appetite resulting from the exposure to a new flavour*").

Comment: If I OD on the food today, I won't want any tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

["sick of..."](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sick+of)

*"Mom, please don't make waffles again today.  You've made waffles every morning for the past three months and now I'm thoroughly sick of waffles!"*

---

This phrasing alone does not connote or denote whether you particularly enjoyed waffles *before* they were doomed by excess - but it does imply that your feelings for waffles have waned to the point of mild hate/disgust.

(This phrasing also does not specify whether you now have a permanent distaste for waffles, or just a temporary distaste for waffles... either situation is possible... and only time will tell if you'll ever enjoy them again.)

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities come to mind. The first is informal and seems suitable for a domestic conversation. The second is a little more neutral in its tone.

1. As an informal and direct way of expressing yourself, you could say “I am **fed up** with waffles”.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fed-up)
> fed up:
> adjective informal:
> annoyed or disgusted by something that you have experienced for too long

2. Another, more neutral, expression is “Waffles have **palled** on me”.

Merriam Webster offers a good selection of constructions to illustrate the usage of the verb *pall*.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pall)
> pall
> intransitive verb:
> 1 : to lose strength or effectiveness
> 2 : to lose in interest or attraction
> *his humor began to pall on us*
> *He found that his retirement hobbies began to pall after a couple of years*
> 3 : dwindle
> *our enthusiasm soon palled*
> transitive verb:
> 1 : to cause to become insipid
> 2 : to deprive of pleasure in something by satiating
> *The choicest delicacies pall the stomach in time*

So, if waffles have palled on you, it means you liked them but have eaten so many that you do so no longer. It is possible your appetite for them will return at some future time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could write this, in most cases no special vocabulary is used: 'I grew up on a strawberry farm, and I ate so many strawberries I can't stand them any more."

"I can't stand" is just a colloquial expression for "I hate", and has no special connotations with food.

The most food-related word (which is not that common), however, is 'surfeit'.

E.g. the children's book Many Moons

*Once upon a time, in a kingdom by the sea, there lived a little Princess named Lenore. She was ten years old, going on eleven.*

*One day Lenore fell ill of a surfeit of raspberry tarts and took to her bed.*

Surfeit is not limited to food, and means either "over consumption" or "over supply". E.g. "Bangladesh has a surfeit of cheap labour, which limits investment in technology" - "Bangladesh has a huge amount of cheap labour".

So for example

"Following the surfeit of seafood at the buffet last week, I don't want to see another crab leg as long as I live."

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you are looking for is ***surfeit***.

*I've eaten a surfeit of oysters and as a result now heartily detest them*.

*Surfeit* has other meanings too - but OED sense 6 is given as:

*Satiety, repletion; weariness or disgust arising from excess, esp. excess of food or drink. Also: an instance of this.*

And its most recent example:

*2002   Observer 10 Nov. (Food Monthly Suppl.) 56/2   He defines and defends gourmandisme..following it through the various stages of delight and surfeit to its logical conclusion.*